# how to show 3 images in notification big view

Tags: android, notifications

how can I show 3 images in notification big view?

I know that BigPictureStyle allows showing a picture in the big view, but I want to show 3 pictures, like in the new york times app.

Comment: you can customize the layout of your notification

Comment: Create RemoteView and set to your Notification

Comment: I want the normal view to be standard, but the big view should contain 3 images. If you know how to do it please post an answer.

Comment: @MahmoudBadri wait for while let me check it and upload one snap plz

Comment: @MahmoudBadri hey post one snap

Answer (score 0):

You should write Your own notification style.
Check out this tutotrial http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/

Comment: I dont want a fully custom notification layout, just the big view of the notification should contain 3 images, but the normal view is just standard.

Comment: But I suposse that standard notification style cannot display 3 images

Comment: also the example you provided is for normal notifications, I need to the custom layout to be for the big notification.